# JavaScript/JQuery slider that will work with AJAX/JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am looking for non-commercial JavaScript/JQuery slider or some tutorial with slider which works fine with dynamically inserted data with AJAX/JSON. Could anyone advise some. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything or even google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

**Example** 
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax.html